# Creating a matrix which stacks the contents of matrices from nested loops

Tags: python, loops, matrix

Hi I'm new to python and have the following problem.

The below simplifies by using two matrices:

- x with dim 6x4, and
- c with dim 4x4:

I would like to end up with a 6 by 4 matrix via the following steps

1. take the first row of x, call it j
2. create a 4 x 4 matrix by taking each column element in j and subtracting it by itself and the other three elements in j, do that for the other three column elements, and then stack those resulting four rows with 1x4 dimensions together
3. multiply that matrix by the above scaling matrix y to create a new matrix (say z) of same 4X4 dimension
4. sum down the rows of each column in z to reduce z to a 1 X 4 array
5. repeat steps 1 to 4 above for each of the remaining 5 rows of x
6. And then stack the resulting 6 z matrices (each of 1X4 dim from step 4) together into a 6X4

I can easily do steps 1 to 4 if my starting x matrix is 1X4, for eg:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
c=np.random.rand(4,4)
y=np.zeros((4,4))
for i in range(4):
    j=x[0,i]-x
    y[i,:]=np.vstack(j)
    z=y*c
weights=z.sum(axis=0)type here
```

But if i try to extend this in a nested loop for a larger dimension x (eg. 6x4), the following falls over in the last line:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,2,4,4],[0,5,3,4],[1,2,1,4],[1,0,3,4],[4,2,3,3]])
c=np.random.rand(4,4)
y=np.zeros((4,4))
z_weights_time=np.zeros((6,4))
for s in range(6):
   d=x[[s],:]
   for i in range(4):
      j=d[0,i]-d
      y[i,:]=np.vstack(j)
      z=y*c
      z_weights=z.sum(axis=0)
print("y= ",y)
print("c= ",c)
print("z_weights= ",z_weights)
z_weights_time[s,:]=np.vstack(z_weights)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting to your question supporting evidence.

Comment: Thanks! It reads :  
File "<ipython-input-9-8c046e6ccc77>", line 15, in <module>
    z_weights_time[s,:]=np.vstack(z_weights)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4,)

Comment: the shape of the arrays are not the same. In line 15, depending on your objective, you need to either change the shape of `z_weights_time[s,:]` OR `np.vstack(z_weights_time)`

Answer (score 1):

x is a 3d array.
Lets say c isn't random but set as in the screenprint below:
[image: Screenprint]

Then using your code and logic this should work:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[[1,2,3,4]],[[2,2,4,4]],[[0,5,3,4]],[[1,2,1,4]],[[1,0,3,4]],[[4,2,3,3]]])
c=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
y=np.zeros((4,4))
z_weights=np.zeros((6,4))
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(4):
        j=x[row,0,col]-x[row]
        print(f'x[row,0,col] - x[row] = {x[row,0,col]} - {x[row]} = {j}')
        y[col,:]=np.vstack(j)
        z=y*c
    print(f'z_weights@row{row}=z.sum(axis=0) = {z.sum(axis=0)}')
    z_weights[[row],:] = z.sum(axis=0)
print(f'z_weights = \n {z_weights}')
```

Comment: Thanks! I see you had to create a 3 dimension array to solve this - I never would have thought of that as in my real application the 6 is a time dimension with more entries, but your prototype works! Much appreciated!